# are they any implications if i reduce a sha256 result into 248 bits?

Tags: hash

i am working a prototype using some cryptographic properties.
the question is simple but perhaps deep enough for me to decide :

sha256 is a strong hash function, but i have space for 248 bits only.
my guess is if i remove any 8 bits the resulting mySHA248 will keep
all good properties with slightly less entropy/collision resistance.

Comment: it's true for any subset of bits of any good cryptohash. If sha256 doesn't had this property, it will be never standardized by USA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get slightly more collisions, which is not a problem in many use cases, but overall hash properties are preserved.

If some hash loses its properties by omitting last few characters (or any selected ones), then hash is flawwed by having internal correlated structure.

In fact, [NIST publication](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/fips/180/3/archive/2008-10-31/documents/fips180-3_final.pdf#page29) effectively trims hash to desired number of bits.

Comment: from NIST Special Publication 800-107 - 5.1.2. The λ left-most bits of the full-length message digest shall be selected as the truncated message digest. : That clarifies my 'if i remove ANY 8 bits' , ANY shall be 'right-most' bits. good to know ,thanks Evil

Comment: I didn't understand what you're saying in the second paragraph of your answer.

Comment: @D.W. Edited, I meant that hash bits should have uniform properties. If we have say 16bytes hash, and select say 12 bytes, it shouldn't matter which one are chosen, otherwise there are "more secure" bytes inside. Such internal flaw is a place to start cracking, I hope it is clearer right now.

Comment: @ Evil your edited sentence can support my initial 'ANY 8 bits' but now there is a new question : from my prev comment NIST text i think it implies MSB-like value for hash digests .. Have a nice day both and Thanks a lot.